# I need to have multiple line entries on my imported json file from php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, forms

I'm working on a program and I can't figure out where to throw the extra write command that would allow for multiple entries, to be pushed into my final array, that would allow it to be reimported when a new post comes in.  Any ideas?  The check.json file is only keeping one entry...

```
<?php
#$myFile = file("check.json", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);       
$myFile = "check.json";
#$arr_data = array(); // create empty array
$code = $_POST['code'];
    try
    {
        //Get form data
        $formdata = array(
           $code=> $_POST['cpu'],
        );
        //Get data from existing json file
        $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        // converts json data into array
        $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);       
        // loops through the formdata array
        foreach ($formdata as $f) { 
        #if data is in there then replace
            if(in_array($f, $arr_data)) {
                echo "$f is found...";
                foreach ($arr_data as $a) {
                    if (strpos($a, $f) !== false) {
                        echo "$a is checking in...", "<br>";
                        // Push user data to array

                    }   
                    else 
                        echo "Formdata is subtracted by 1...", "<br>";
                        // Push user data to array, minus 1 from value
                }   
            }
            else 
                echo "$f is Not in the array..."."<br>";
                // Push user data to array
                array_push($arr_data,$formdata);
                //Convert updated array to JSON
                $jsondata = json_encode($formdata);            
                //write json data into data.json file
                if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
                    echo 'Data successfully saved';
                }
                else 
                    echo "error";
        }       
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
?>
```

t9.html

```
<form action="test9.php" method="POST">
CPU Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="cpu">
<br><br/>
Code:<br>
<input type="text" name="code">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

check.json
    {"10":"Tommy"}

Answer (score 0):

Every time you `file_put_contents()` you are rewriting the entire file -- erasing whatever is in it, and writing out the current contents of `$jsondata`  What you want to do is read that file up into `$jsondata`, modify `$jsondata` with the new value(s), then write it back out again.